# Adding validation to controllers in Cake 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In CakePHP 3.x is it acceptable to add validation rules within a controller?

I've read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html but it doesn't actually say *where* you (can / should) add your methods.

I understand that typically these go in src/Model/Table/ModelName.php. However I'm trying to validate a form which is not tied to a particular database table and doesn't need a corresponding model.

I'm familar with Cake 2.x where I would typically do this in the controller, or possibly add a model with $useTable = false. But in this case the simplest method seems to add the rules directly in the controller, but I wasn't sure whether this is bad practice. If the rules don't go in the controller where should they be put?

Context - this is a form where the user is doing a search. It requires some input and I'm trying to validate 3 fields: email, quantity and a postcode. Cake's validator has inbuilt features to do the first two but in the case of postcode I'll need to add a custom method.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In CakePHP 3.x is it acceptable to add validation rules within a controller?

Technically possible, but I would consider it as *bad practice*.

> I understand that typically these go in src/Model/Table/ModelName.php. However I'm trying to validate a form which is not tied to a particular database table and doesn't need a corresponding model.

There is a whole section called ["Modelless Forms" in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html) that covers that use case.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That was what I couldn't find!